# Predicates Validity

Tags: first-order-logic, predicate-logic

Which of the following formulas are true:

```
A.(∀x∀y (P(x,y)=>P(y,x)))=>∀z P(z,z)
B. ∀x∀y (P(x,y)=>(P(y,x)=>∀z P(z,z)))
C. (∀x P(x))=> ∃y P(y)
D. none of the above
```

My Question is How do we approach problems like that?? the only thing coming to my head is to turn them into CNF, so for example from (A) we'll get:

```
(∀x∀y(¬P(x,y)∨P(y,x)))=>∀z P(z,z)
(∃x∃y(P(x,y)∧¬P(y,x)))∨∀z P(z,z)
```

Eventually I will have from (A) the following two rules:

```
1) P(c1,c2)∨P(z,z)
2) ¬P(c2,c1)∨P(z,z)
```

Does this Mean that A is Not Valid because I can't reach (True) from the above two Rules??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prove that a formula is 'true' ... by which I assume they mean 'valid' ... i.e. *always true*, you can negate the statement, and show that that leads to a contradiction. So, if you use the resolution method: negate the statement, put into CNF, get the clauses, and see if you can resolve it to the empty clause. If so, then that negation of the original statement was a contradiction, meaning that the original statement itself was valid.

For, for example, take the third statement. Negated:

$\neg (\forall x \ P(x) \to \exists y \ P(y))$

which is equivalent to:

$\forall x \ P(x) \land  \neg  \exists y \ P(y)$

and thus to:

$\forall x \ P(x) \land  \forall y \ \neg  P(y)$

this gives two clauses:

$P(x)$

and

$\neg P(y)$

and they immediately resolve to the empty clause, meaning that $\forall x \ P(x) \to \exists y \ P(y)$ is valid ('true')

Now to demonstrate that some statement is *not* valid, simply provide a counterexample.

For example, for the first one, take as your domain a single object $a$, and have it *not* stand in relation $P$ to itself. Then $\forall x \forall y (P(x,y) \to P(y,x))$ is (vacuously) true, but $\forall z \ P(z,z)$ is false, and hence $\forall x \forall y (P(x,y) \to P(y,x)) \to \forall z \ P(z,z)$ is false.

Comment: Can't Thank you enough Today, It's clear now

Comment: @MiriamArbaji My pleasure! :)